# data exists but my program says "No data exists for the row/column"

Tags: c#

Please guide me how to resolve this.

```
    if (Convert.ToInt32(rd["B_Quan"].ToString()) > 3)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Oops sobra tama na ");
    }
    cn.Close();
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You've provided quite a lot of code, with no indication as to exactly what's happening, what you expected to happen, or what diagnostics you've been through so far. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: "Oops sobra tama na " tagalog bayan?

Comment: if (Convert.ToInt32(rd["B_Quan"].ToString()) > 3)    << ERROR

Comment: Sorry guys im new here :(

Comment: @LeonelSarmiento yes sir tagalog po yan

Comment: @AubreyjoyIsola You should explain your problem and the exception of your code.

Comment: @AubreyjoyIsola We don't know if you're getting a `NullReferenceException` or `FormatException` or etc... . please tell us more...

Comment: in that codes, they count it how much the user borrowed books. And everytime I search the student id it errors and it will display "no data exists for row/column" @LeonelSarmiento

Answer (score 0):

A row/column either doesn't exist or contains null. 
In which case you will receive a `NullReferenceException` because `null` doesn't have a function `.ToString()`

You could check for this:

```
if (rd.Table.Columns.Contains("B_Quan") && rd["B_Quan"] != null)
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(rd["B_Quan"].ToString()) > 3)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Oops sobra tama na ");
    }
}
cn.Close();
```

---

What does this do?

```
using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
{
    dt.Load(rd);
    Console.WriteLine(dt.Rows.Count);
}
if (Convert.ToInt32(rd["B_Quan"].ToString()) > 3)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Oops sobra tama na ");
}
```

While debugging, can you open up `dt` and view your table? Does if have a column named "B_Quan"?

Comment: The condition will be useless because I assured that the `rd['B_Quan']` will  return null, not until the `SqlDataReader.Read()` is executed.

Comment: There was not `SqlDataReader` in your code until Leonel pointed out that there is an edit history where you did. Have you tried it? Because if you assured that it will be null, then `&& rd["B_Quan"] != null` will catch that.

Comment: I assured because without executing the `SqlDataReader.Read()` the `rd["B_Quan"]` will not retrieve any data, and it will be pointless because you can't take any data in the column even if there's a data in it... I wish I could try it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your reason why you remove your code in your question.

For the sake of this question I copied your code from the edit history.

I think, the reason why you receive the *"No data exists"* in your code is because you don't use the `SqlDataReader.Read()` yet. See [SqlDataReader Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx) for more info.

**Sample:**

```
    while(rd.Read()) // You need to read first to get your data.
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(rd["B_Quan"].ToString()) > 3)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Oops sobra tama na ");
        }
    }
```

**You code:**

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        cn.Open();
    }  
    string student = "Select * From tbl_student";

    OleDbCommand loadstudent = new OleDbCommand(student, cn);
    loadstudent.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SId", textBox8.Text + "%");

    rd = loadstudent.ExecuteReader();

    if (rd.HasRows == true)
    {
        // ipapalabas ung labas
        while (rd.Read())
        {

        messageBox.Show("Oops sobra tama na ");

        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No record(s) found.");
    }
    cn.Close();

    if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        cn.Open();
    }
    string s = "Select * From Borrow";

    OleDbCommand sa = new OleDbCommand(s, cn);
    loadstudent.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SId", textBox8.Text + "%");

    rd = sa.ExecuteReader();

    while(rd.Read()) // You need to read first to get your data.
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(rd["B_Quan"].ToString()) > 3)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Oops sobra tama na ");
        }
    }
    cn.Close();

    if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) cn.Open();

    cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * From Borrow", cn);
    rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();// ipapalitaw
    if (rd.HasRows == true)
    {
        // ipapalabas ung labas
        while (rd.Read())
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(rd["B_Quan"].ToString()) > 3)

            {
                MessageBox.Show("Oops sobra tama na ");
                return;

            }
        }
    }
}
```